# my script is showing add as friend even user is my friend

Tags: php

i have below script about add new friend. It is working properly in two cases and have problem in one side. for example, If A sends friend request to B and C. When B accepts his request and C still not accepted. In case if C 'waiting for approval' is working. condition 1 is not working. Means even if A is your friend u can still send request. below is the script:

```
<?php
$querToCheck    =   "SELECT * FROM friends WHERE accepted = '2' AND ((user_one = '$activeID' AND user_two = '$fid') OR (user_one = '$fid' AND user_two = '$activeID' ) )";

$resToCheck     =   mysql_query($querToCheck);

if(mysql_num_rows($resToCheck)==2)
{
    $addFriend  =   "Friends";      
}
else
{
    $querToCheck    =   "SELECT * FROM friends WHERE accepted = '1' AND ((user_one = '$activeID' AND user_two = '$fid') OR (user_one = '$fid' AND user_two = '$activeID' ) )";

    $resToCheck     =   mysql_query($querToCheck);

    if(mysql_num_rows($resToCheck)==1)
    {
        $addFriend  =   "Waiting For Approval";
    }
    else
    {
        $querToCheck    =   "SELECT * FROM friends WHERE accepted = '0' AND ((user_one = '$activeID' AND user_two = '$fid') OR (user_one = '$fid' AND user_two = '$activeID' ) )";
        $resToCheck     =   mysql_query($querToCheck);

        if(mysql_num_rows($resToCheck)==0)
        {
            $addFriend  =   '<a href="addAsFriend.php?sid='.$row['id'].'" style="color:#FFFFFF;font-size:14px;">Add As Friend</a>';
        }
    }
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Psst, use the `{}` button...

Comment: First of all you have an extra `}` at the end of the script

Comment: above is my script. script that update friend table is working correctly. only the issue is in above script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you must check for the `accepted` column value rather than checking for the number of rows returned

```
<?php
$addFriend = "";
$querToCheck = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM friends WHERE (user_one = '$activeID' AND user_two = '$fid') OR (user_one = '$fid' AND user_two = '$activeID' ) ");
if(mysql_num_rows($querToCheck) > 0)
{
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($querToCheck);
    $accepted = $row['accepted'];

    if($accepted == 1)
    {
        $addFriend  = "Waiting For Approval";
    } else if($accepted == 2)
    {
        $addFriend  = "Friends";  
    } 
}
else
{
    $addFriend  = '<a href="addAsFriend.php?sid='.$row['id'].'" style="color:#FFFFFF;font-size:14px;">Add As Friend</a>'; 
}
?>
```

Comment: dear, thanks for ur help. It is now working good in case of 'waiting for approval' and 'friends' and now it is now showing 'add As Friend' button/link

Comment: please help me to find out last one issue.Please note that, there is no value for new users.

Comment: Dear Khawer Zeshan, if u try on old code i think u can solve my issue. Thanks

Comment: Dear Khawer Zeshan, it is now working properly thanks for your kind help. Thank u very much.

Comment: As i have joined this fourm today i do not know how to accept answer. Please guide me

Comment: There is a tick a symbol on the left of my answer. you can click on it and it will turn green which means answer is accepted. also if you click on up arrow on the left it will give me vote that this answer was helpful

Comment: thanks, i accepted your answer but i do not qualify to give vote to u because i do not have 15 reputations.